# Xamarin.Forms and FCM implementation not working

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an Android application with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms. For push notifications, I'm using Xamarin.Firebase (v 42.1001.0). I followed the sample implementation here: https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/tree/master/firebase-messaging/samples

But if I implement this, I only get a token, which I can't use in the firebase console. It says, that no device with this token is registered. But the device can subscribe for topics, which appear in the console after a while. So the configuration file from firebase, I imported, must be correct. And my firebase messaging receiver never gets called. Only the OnTokenRefresh of my FirebaseInstanceIdService, if the app is reinstalled.

I also added my developer machine's finger print to the firebase console.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while since this question was asked, but I recently ran into the same problem. So I thought, might as well share my finding.

Just so you know I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise and although I don't think this has anything to do with the solution, I thought it was better I mention it beforehand. As of now, I've successfully tested FCM on Android, so although this solution is for Xamarin Forms as of now I'm posting only the solution for Android. I'll add a solution for iOS once I finish testing it.

You would have to create a Firebase Project before you start, so I suggest you refer this link [Xamarin Documention : FCM](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/firebase-cloud-messaging/)

**ANDROID :**

Create a blank Xamarin forms Solution. Open the Android project and Add this Nuget Package [Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging/42.1021.1). This will add all the necessary packages for you. Once you've added this, next include the google-services.json
file from your Firebase Console. For more information on this go to this [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/#Add_the_Google_Services_JSON_File). Now add the following Permissions in your AndroidManifest file

`<permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />`

${applicationId} will be replaced with your Application package name.

You can follow the rest of the steps provided in the Tutorial [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/#Check_for_Google_Play_Services)

And you should be good.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I already could solve the issue a few days ago. I just updated the FCM library and it worked as expected - without any code-change. :-)

Comment: @Mahadev - Please share your ios push notification for xamarin poc details also.